# Null WebApplicationContext in integration test

Tags: rest, spring-boot, integration-testing

I have pulled an integration test from a tutorial to test an API secured via OAuth2 (with Google as the authorisation host).  I am using a MockMVC object and setting the webAppContext via webApplication context, but when I run it, I immediately get an IllegalArgument exception on the webApplicationContext.

I have searched StackOverflow and I see this has come up a lot, but none of the answers solve my problem. Most suggest adding the @RunWith and @WebAppConfiguration annotation, which I have done.  But it is still not working. Assistance would be much appreciated.

```
package xyz;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.authentication;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.TestingAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientContext;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.DefaultOAuth2AccessToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Request;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public class TempTest4  {

    @Autowired private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testGetAuthenticationInfo() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/token")
                .with(authentication(getOauthTestAuthentication()))
                .sessionAttr("scopedTarget.oauth2ClientContext", getOauth2ClientContext()))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.username").value("bwatkins"))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.token").value("my-fun-token"));
    }

    private Authentication getOauthTestAuthentication() {
        return new OAuth2Authentication(getOauth2Request(), getAuthentication());
    }

    private OAuth2Request getOauth2Request () {
        String clientId = "oauth-client-id";
        Map<String, String> requestParameters = Collections.emptyMap();
        boolean approved = true;
        String redirectUrl = "http://my-redirect-url.com";
        Set<String> responseTypes = Collections.emptySet();
        Set<String> scopes = Collections.emptySet();
        Set<String> resourceIds = Collections.emptySet();
        Map<String, Serializable> extensionProperties = Collections.emptyMap();
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("Everything");

        OAuth2Request oAuth2Request = new OAuth2Request(requestParameters, clientId, authorities,
            approved, scopes, resourceIds, redirectUrl, responseTypes, extensionProperties);

        return oAuth2Request;
    }

    private Authentication getAuthentication() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("Everything");

        User userPrincipal = new User("user", "", true, true, true, true, authorities);

        HashMap<String, String> details = new HashMap<String, String>();
        details.put("user_name", "bwatkins");
        details.put("email", "bwatkins@test.org");
        details.put("name", "Brian Watkins");

        TestingAuthenticationToken token = new TestingAuthenticationToken(userPrincipal, null, authorities);
        token.setAuthenticated(true);
        token.setDetails(details);

        return token;
    }

    private OAuth2ClientContext getOauth2ClientContext () {
        OAuth2ClientContext mockClient = mock(OAuth2ClientContext.class);
        when(mockClient.getAccessToken()).thenReturn(new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken("my-fun-token"));

        return mockClient;
    }     
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the following annotations before your class declaration?@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserEndpoints.class) // This will be different for your use case

Comment: Thanks Brandon.  I replaced @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) with @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) and added @WebMvcTest([MyEndPoint].class) but it didn't work.  It doesn't even start up Spring like with my other tests.  It fails immediately.